# Autohotkey ELSE statements not working. Any replacement?

Tags: autohotkey

I‘m making an autohotkey script.

What the problem is that the ELSE commands are sometimes not working.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the AHK if-else control flow. Maybe you should show some code and we could tell you what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use IF commands instead.

For example:

```
<^<!-::
If GetKeyState ("u", "p")
MsgBox hey!
If not GetKeyState ("u", "p")
MsgBox bye!
```

*hope that helped.*

Answer (score 1):

When you code in AHK v1, one of the most common sources of confusion is the distinction between the deprecated, traditional `if` statements and more reasonable, modern `if` statements using expressions.

The [official documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm) says:

> An *If* statement that contains an expression is usually differentiated from a traditional If statement such as `if FoundColor != Blue` by enclosing the expression in parentheses, ...

What happened to you was that you meant to use modern, universal `if` statements when AHK interpreted them as deprecated ones, which was why your `else` didn't get recognized.

The parentheses aren't really required every single time, but until you get the hang of it, make sure you use them as in:

```
if (expression)
  DoThis
else
  OrThat
```